# Why do some reviews can't be viewed in Developer Console?

Tags: google-play-console, google-console-developer

Recently, I received a 5-star rating for one of my android app but the problem is I can't view it / reply it in my developer console.

[image: Google Console Developer Console]

Replying on it, fetches me this message:

[image: Google Console Developer Console - Error Message]

It happened with me some time back also when someone from Canada reviewed my Yoga app but Google filtered it. I researched this issue that time also but Google didn't responded well on it as to why this happens when you have enabled those countries.

Why does Google don't rank my apps Up if my app gets good ranking but it immediately pulls down my app if I get even one 1-star/2-star rankings. Why is google partial about it. I'm not happy with this. :(

Can anybody give a detailed explanation to this or what are some unexplored Developer Console hacks, that we still don't know?

Answer (score 0):

It is because of their auto filter. Sometimes they will delete your review, then you can't view it in your console. It only happens with positive ratings (they assume that people won't fake negative reviews by default). You can try to edit your review or delete it then review again, then you can view it in your console :)